# ipod touch kCLErrorDomain Code=0 Operation Could not be completed

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch, core-location

HI , i m using CoreLocation Framework and getting the location. in Simulator it is working fine . but when i am deploying the app in my iPod Touch 2G with OS 2.2.1 .. it is giving my a strange error ..

Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "Operation could not be completed.(kCLErrorDomain error 0.)"

What to do ?? can anyone help ??

Comment: I still have the same problem, just using the Twitter app on iPhone 4. No dev stuff, just plain usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have WiFi switched on, the iPod has no way of determining the current location. Even if you do, not all WiFi networks are supported for GeoLocation.

Comment: i have a wifi network and it is working fine .. everything is working fine .. but this is not ...

Comment: In the Simulator, Core Location fakes it and always gives you 1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino as the location. If you're running Snow Leopard, go to the "Time Zone" pane of the Date and Time preference pane and see if it can locate you. If it can't, your iPod touch won't be able to either. Adding your WiFi network to http://www.skyhookwireless.com/ should enable your network to be used for location.

Comment: … also, you should really code your app to be able to gracefully deal with location services being unavailable like this.